# Secure public API

Tags: injection

I'm building a mobile app that will use API created by me on my server. These API will be publicy exposed, but not publicy documented. I want to let the user to use the app without authentication for a faster user experience. Lets assume the purpose of the app is "polls", so the user will create and vote for different polls. I want to be sure that an hacker user will not be able (for example) to vote multiple time for the same poll (or do anything else bad).

I know that's very simple to trace HTTPS traffic and perform similar API call and do bad things on the DB. In order to avoid that, I was thinking about generating client side a string that is the timestamp encrypted with AES and a fixed password (same for every client and carved in the source code) known only by the server, the server will then decrypt the string and check the timestamp. [Doing this I'm supposing none can decompile and find the PWD inside the source code]

Do you know any better approaches? I don't want to reinvent the wheel, but I guess OAuth will not solve my problems here.

Examples for better understanding:

API1: retrieve available polls --> I don't want that an attaker will call multiple time this API in order to avoid to read the DB on malicoius calls

API2: submit the poll valutation --> I don't want that an attaker will call multiple time this API in order to falsificate the results

Thanks very much for your help

Comment: A sufficiently determined attacker _will_ try to decompile the code. You could use public-key cryptography, where the public key is in the client and the private keys kept in secret by the server.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But how this is different from my solution? i.e. if you're able to find the public key you're done.

Comment: You put a different public key in each copy of the code, so you can verify that the same device wasn't used multiple times.